# Question on an exponential distribution, Y

Tags: statistics

Let Y be an exponential distributed random variable with mean $\beta$. Define a random variable $X$ in the following way: $X=k$ if $k-1 \le Y \le k$ for $k=1,2,...$

Find $P(X=k) for each $k=1,2,...$

Show that your answers to part (a) can be written as

$P(X=k)=e^{(-\frac{1}{\beta})^{k-1}}(1-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta})}$ and that $X$ has a geometric distribution with $p=(1-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}$

---

$f(y)=\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}$

$Y=X-1 \rightarrow k=X=Y+1$

$P[X=k]=P[Y=y+1]=\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{(y+1)}{\beta}}$

Then, it does not yield the answer and I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$X = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\mathsf 1_{[k-1,k]}(Y), $$
and so 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X=k) &= \mathbb P(k-1\leqslant Y\leqslant k)\\
 &= \left(1-e^{-\frac1\beta k}\right)-\left(1-e^{-\frac1\beta(k-1)}\right)\\
&= e^{-\frac1\beta(k-1)} - e^{-\frac1\beta k}\\
&= e^{-\frac1\beta(k-1)}\left(1-e^{-\frac1\beta}\right),\quad k=1,2,\ldots.
\end{align}
It follows that $X$ has $\mathrm{Geo}\left(1-e^{-\frac1\beta} \right)$ distribution.